# Solving Resistor Array with Voltages at Nodes

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistor-ladder

[image: Image showing array of 5 resistor nodes, each powered with V_x, but only 3 are on.]

Hello, I've been having a lot of trouble with this problem from my intro circuits class. The questions before this covered simplifying circuits by combining resistors. However, now that there's an additional V_x in each resistor loop, I'm having trouble figuring out how to solve it. I've gotten to a point where I've eliminated the parts of the circuit that the open switches block, but feel like I am approaching the rest of the problem the wrong way. My professor and TA when I asked them acted as though the problem has a very straightforward solution so I'm concerned I might be overcomplicating it. Below is my work so far involving a painful system of 8 or so equations. Thank you to anyone that might be able to shed some light on this.

[image: Attempted solution that is devolving into algebraic madness]

Comment: are the switches in the diagram in the ON position, or in the OFF position? ... there is no ON or OFF position in double throw switches per se

Comment: in the opening sentence, the word pattern appears. Have you identified the pattern? That makes the deriviation of voltages so much easier.

Comment: To me it looks like an inverted R-2R ladder network found in all electronics textbooks.